# Intersect/overlay multiple geodataframes from list using python (geopandas)

Tags: python, geopandas, intersection, batch, geodataframe

I am trying to overlay multiple gdf from list at once.

I have tried this code:

```
GDF_list = [gdf_1, gdf_2, gdf_3, gdf_4]

for DVP in GDF_list:
    DVP = gpd.overlay(gdf, GDF_list, how='intersection')
    DVP['area'] =DVP.apply(lambda row: row.geometry.area,axis=1)
```

But I am getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'crs'

Any Idea how to proceed this "batch" intersection using Python?

Answer (score 2):

The second df in the overlay should in your code be `DVP` and not `GDF_list`. Try this:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import os

maindf = gpd.read_file(r"C:\GIS\temp\rectangles.shp") #The frame you want to intersect all others with.
df2 = gpd.read_file(r"C:\GIS\temp\ovals.shp")
df3 = gpd.read_file(r"C:\GIS\temp\hexagonss.shp")
    
inputframes = [df2, df3]
resultframes = [] #An empty list to hold the results

for frame in inputframes:
    result = gpd.overlay(df1=maindf, df=frame, how="intersection")
    result['area'] = result.geometry.area
    resultframes.append(result)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. - But what if I want to work with these edited dataframes further and not saving them into shp.,?

Comment: Append result to an empty list

Comment: I have tried this:
`for e, frame in enumerate(frames, 1):
    result = gpd.overlay(df1=lokality, df2=frame, how="intersection", keep_geom_type=True)
    result['area'] =result.apply(lambda row: row.geometry.area,axis=1)
    frames.append(result)`

But I am having a memory error. @BERA

Comment: I would like to achieve the result that the each dataframe in the list would have a new collumn "area" - with: `result['area'] =result.apply(lambda row: row.geometry.area,axis=1)`, @BERA

Comment: Just add that line below the  `result=gpd.overlay(...` line inside the for loop

Comment: Specifically, I can only see the "result" dataframe which contain the overlay of the first dataframe in the list only.  I am not able to see the results for the rest of the dataframes in the list.

Comment: And if I add the: `frames.append(result)` below, I'll get the "memory error".

Comment: If you append the result to frames list the loop will keep intersecting forever, you should append them to an empty list. See my updated answer.

Comment: @BRERA Great, thank you. One last question. Can I somehow rename the dataframes within the new list based on the dataframes inside my old list?